# Local repository on my mac to remote linux server

Tags: git

I'm new to Git and just playing around at the minute but I'm keen to start implementing it into my projects.

I have installed Git on both my local Mac and my Remote Linux server.

I have a project I've been working on, on my local Mac and it has been tracked by Git and has files and changes that have been commit.

The issue I have now is I don't know how to get them to my remote server.

So I have the domain and project root set up on my server at 
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/

My understanding is I have to create a blank repository? Then publish from my local repository? I'm guessing I'll need to set up permission too? I'm just unsure on the steps. I am a total noob with git so please go easy on me :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to configure a local remote to point to a repository.  What happens on the remote repository will depend on the provider (e.g. GitHub, Bitbucket, etc.).  Once your remote is configured, all you need to do is to `git push` your branch.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have installed Git on your remote server. Just needed to be sure you installed Git server (like Gitblit, Gitlab, Gitorius) and not Git client.

After you have installed Git server on your server, you just need to create an empty repository in your Git server for your project and add permission for users for that repo. Then in your development machine, you just do the following:

```
git remote add origin http://your.server/yourproject.git
git push -u origin --all
```

Comment: I did yum install git-all. Didn't know I needed anything else. 
I can create repositories on my remote server so I assumed this was enough. 

I don't understand the http://your.server/yourproject.git on my remote server there isn't a project on there yet?

Comment: @craigb88 Looks like you just installed the Git client not Git server. your.server is the name of your server and yourproject.git is the name you give your empty repository (preferably the same as the name of your application). For example your server name is abcserver and you created a new repository for your project such as "abcscheduler", the command would look like `git remote add origin http://abcserver/abcscheduler.git`

Comment: @craigb88 I stand corrected looks like you can get away with just installing Git on the server but if you want GUI then you can try Gitlab or something similar. Anyway, [this link](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-run-your-own-git-server) should give you step-by-step on how to setup Git on local and server and how to use Git.